# How to redirect page before page is fully reload?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, reload, lifecycle

I know there are similar questions, but none answers to this specific case. I need to redirect to `/` after reload happens, but for my case, when each reload happens the page goes through authentication/authorization process (checks for permissions) and then it comes to my page. After this long process happens, it simply shows the old page.

My code that does not work:

```
ngOnInit() {
  @HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event']) 
   this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
  }
}
```

Do I need to use a different lifecyle?

Thanks.

Comment: @VVS described the hooks but please let us know which type of jobs do you want to do before redirection. because for example authentication/authorization verification should handle in Guards.

Comment: Only  authentication/authorization verification for now.

Comment: So please check Route Guards in Angular. That's a better approach for auth verifications.

Answer (score 0):

The lifecycle hooks for Angular are in the following order:

- Constructor
- ngOnChanges
- ngOnInit
- ngDoCheck
- ngAfterContentInit
- ngAfterContentChecked
- ngAfterViewInit
- ngAfterViewChecked
- ngOnDestroy

So if you want to call something before the initialization of the component or directive (ngOnInit) then your probably best to do this in the constructor.

More info on lifecycle hooks can be found [here](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks).

Also from looking at your code, I believe your trying to do something like this:

```ts
@Component({ 
  selector: 'something',
  ...
)}

class SomeComponent {
  @HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
  doSomeLogic($event) {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
  }
}
```

or maybe like this:

```ts
@Component({ 
  selector: 'something',
  host: {'window:beforeunload':'doSomeLogic'}
  ...
)}
```

or there is this option:

```html
<div (window:beforeunload)="doSomeLogic()"></div>
```

As you mention Authorization, you could create an AuthGuard for that like this (as mentioned in the comments):

```ts
// src/app/auth/auth-guard.service.ts

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {
  constructor(public auth: AuthService, public router: Router) {}
  canActivate(): boolean {
    if (!this.auth.isAuthenticated()) {
      this.router.navigate(['login']);
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

Then you would apply it to your routes that require Authorization to get to:

```ts
// src/app/app.routes.ts
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { 
    path: 'profile',
    component: ProfileComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard] 
  },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];
```

The [canActive](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate) is described below:

> Interface that a class can implement to be a guard deciding if a route can be activated. If all guards return true, navigation continues. If any guard returns false, navigation is cancelled. If any guard returns a UrlTree, the current navigation is cancelled and a new navigation begins to the UrlTree returned from the guard.